# error with cairo + freeglut combination

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, cairo, freeglut

I make a `GL` context with `freeglut` like this:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_STENCIL);
```

and a draw with `cairo` like this:

```
  if (!device_)
  {
    device_ = cairo_glx_device_create(glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
      glXGetCurrentContext());
  }
  // else do nothing

  auto const surface(cairo_gl_surface_create_for_window(device_,
    glXGetCurrentDrawable(), width, height));

  auto const cr(cairo_create(surface));

  // draw using cairo calls

  cairo_destroy(cr);
  cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers(surface); // !!!
  cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
```

If I don't call `cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers()`, but call `glutSwapBuffers()`, nothing shows, but there is an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (X_GLXSwapBuffers)
  Serial number of failed request:  69
  Current serial number in output stream:  72
```

But, if I call `cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers()`, but don't call `glutSwapBuffers()`, the drawing will show and there will be no error. How can I call `glutSwapBuffers()`, not `cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers()` and not trigger the error? I'd like to mix other content alongside `cairo` content.

Comment: If Cairo wraps GLX as this suggests, then you should go through it. FreeGLUT is going to make assumptions that might not hold if cairo is allowed to manage things like the calling thread's active GLX context.

Comment: sure, but I initialize it with `cairo`'s `GLX` context, I don't know if a new one is being created. Maybe someone has been playing with something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `cairo_gl_surface_swapbuffers` should be equivalent to calling `cairo_surface_flush` and afterwards calling the right function for swapping buffers.

So I guess you are looking for `cairo_surface_flush(surface)`?

Comment: No go, still the error comes up. If you have a working example, post it.

Comment: 7 years have passed and now I think you were right.